# Using AWS elastic transcoder, it possible to choose the thumbnail frame?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm using AWS transcoder to output a MP4 video & jpg poster thumbnail. Everything works fine but the thumbnail is always the first frame of the video which sometimes can be just blank. I'd like the thumbnail to be captured at say 2 secs into the video. I can't see any setting to adjust this, it is possible?

My current setting is:

```
"Outputs" : [
{"ThumbnailPattern" : "video-{count}"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define in the preset that you use for the Job : interval generate in thumbnails

Example preset for Thumbnails with 2 second interval :

```
Format jpg
Interval 2
Max Width 700
Max Height 394
Sizing Policy ShrinkToFit
Padding Policy Pad
```

- The tumbnail with the filename "video-00001.jpg" corresponds to the frame at 0 seconds.
- The tumbnail with the filename "video-00002.jpg" corresponds to the frame at 2 seconds.
- [...]

The file you need is : video-00002.jpg

Here the documentation :
[Transcoder thumbnail preset settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/preset-settings.html#preset-settings-thumbnails)